# Showing JSON as a popup similar to download

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I'm new to front end development and having some trouble displaying json to a new window. Currently, I'm letting the user download the json like this

```
                var blob = new Blob([$scope.data], {type: 'json'});
                var downloadLink = angular.element('<a></a>');
                downloadLink.attr('href', window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
                downloadLink.attr('download', 'data.json');
                downloadLink[0].click();
```

which is nice because when they click download and open the link, the json shows up formatted where they can click on individual parts of it and it will drop down to show more.

I'm trying to get it so they no longer need to download it, and can just open it in a new window. So far, the closest I have gotten is this

```
                var x = window.open();
                x.document.open();
                x.document.write('<html><body><pre>' + $scope.data + '</pre></body></html>');
                x.document.close();
```

Which displays the json, but not formatted. It's one line, and very very long. Is there a good way to format the json so it looks as nice as it does when opening a json file through the browser?

Comment: Can u provide stackblitz?

Comment: sure, what would you like me to add to it other than what I have? I think all the code that's necessary I've already shown

Comment: What you have shown here that code only, but with some dummy data to work with.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to format the json displayed then you can use `JSON.stringify` with [intent parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify),

```js
...
const formattedJson = JSON.stringify($scope.data, null, 4); // Indented 4 spaces also '\t' (tab) is allowed
x.document.write('<html><body><pre>' + formattedJson + '</pre></body></html>');
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you, it formats json well.
https://prettier.io/docs/en/api.html